# the interstitial admob ad not showing on button click until i click back button

Tags: java, android, admob

Hello there i have a problem i've added admob interstitial to my application when i click a button but the problem is when i click the button the ad doesn't shows until  i clicked back button on the phone then the ad shows

the app has 2 activities and the button take u to another activity and i want the ad to show-up before the second  activity appears

this is the code

```
 mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
    tip1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Tips tip = (Tips) DAOTips.lt.get(1);

            intent.putExtra("tip",tip.getTip());
            intent.putExtra("title",tip.getTitle());

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

                mInterstitialAd.show();
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
            }
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are starting the ad but then immediately opening a new screen.

```
        if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {

            mInterstitialAd.show();
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "The interstitial wasn't loaded yet.");
        }
        startActivity(intent);
```

after show is called startActivity is run. You need to remove startActivity otherwise it will be the top activity on the stack and block the ad!

There are two ways,

1) show the ad on oncreate of activity2

2) use admobs listeners. admob has a listener that lets you know when the ad has closed.
you can open the new activity once the ad has closed

```
       mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
         //use this 

        }
    });
```

Comment: but i want the ad to show-up then go to the second activity how i can do that ? by show the ad on the on create event of the second activity ?